# Bash error handling to variable

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

I have a Setup that doesn't work at the moment:

Lets say I have a **program.sh**

```
source path/service_x.sh; install_service_x || error_exit
source path/service_y.sh; install_service_y || error_exit
[...]
```

**A service_y.sh** with the function install_service_y

```
install_service_y() 
{
    [doing funny stuff that likes to fail ;)]
}
```

An **error.sh** 
with the function error_exit inside which is doing many stuff.
Example:

```
error_exit()
{
    echo "{$error}"
    [...]
    echo "Here are the error Logs. Error: {$error} appeared" | mutt -a "a_log_file" -s "failed to install service" -- error@yxz.com
}
```

So, I'm running the program.sh and install_service_y fails, 
I want to have that **error message stored** to a variable **$error** to use it in the error_exit function of the **error.sh**

I really hope that you can understand my setup and whats going wrong.

Comment: You can store errors and output in a variable with `error=$(install_service_y 2>&1) || error_exit`

Comment: Does this work for the whole stuff: error=$(source path/service_x.sh; install_service_x 2>&1) || error_exit

If yes, you're my hero!

Comment: @that-other-guy that won't work, the exist status of the sub-shell will always be zero and exit_error will not execute. Also, stdout will contain good messages (if any)along with errors.

Comment: Important info: source path/service_x.sh; install_service_x || error_exit <- the error_exit function will be executed at the moment, just the error variable doesnt work as described above.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz This is easy to test in your shell... `var=$(false) || echo "Executed"`. And yes, it'll include both errors and outputs as explicitly stated, which seems like a good idea when you're emailing the log.

Comment: @Aeris Yes, this is fine if `service_x.sh` just exports the function you need and not much else.

Comment: @thatotherguy it doesn't work, except that my error=$(source ${SCRIPT_PATH}/script/service_x.sh; install_service_x 2>&1) || error_exit fails with errors that never appeared before :/
+ the script doesn't stop like it does normally.

Comment: @Aeris Conversely, if `service_x.sh` does more than just export the function you need, then it's not fine. How about just leaving it outside as in `source path/service_y.sh; error=$(install_service_y 2>&1) || error_exit`. Note that this assumes that the command is not interactive.

Comment: Hmm, theres no error, when I'm doing it like you recommended.
One of that installin_service things is openssl and that normally throws an "error" while compiling.

Now that script is running without an exit... weird :O

Sad that stackoverflow doesn't allow to post links to a Github Repo, where my project is stored.

Comment: @Aeris It sounds like the script uses `set -e` for its error handling. This is a bad practice because it'll just stop handling errors at all in certain cases, including here (because it runs as part of the left side of a `||`).

Comment: @thatotherguy theres no set -e in the script, but bad practice stuff is included for sure.

I'm not sure if it's allowed (otherwise ignore it / delete it): Theres a user called shoujii on a famous git website and theres a "next" project with a install.sh ;)

I'm really trying to improve my shell skills, but this case isn't the basic stuff (at least for me).
My scripting partner doesn't know how to solve it either :/

Comment: There's no hard rule against [linking to things](https://github.com/shoujii/NeXt-Server), the point is just to make sure the questions and answers are still equally useful in the future when the website inevitably changes (comments matter less). I see that the openssl script uses `exit` instead of `exit 1`, which will not trigger `error_exit` and also now only end the `$(..)` instead of the full script.